# How to fix about Flatpickr recreate

Tags: angularjs, flatpickr

I used flatpickr with angular 1.5.0, es6 env, flatpickr version is 3.0.6, I bind a input events to open flatpickr, when the calendar is open, it closes immediately，but when I tap the input using touchpad, not click, it works well. What is the problem?

I tried using jQuery to bind the event, and the result is the same.
My OS is Mac.

My fragment:

```
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr'

$scope.showPicker = function() {
  flatpickr(document.getElementById('date-input'), {
    locale: zh.zh,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr) {
      $scope.currDay = dateStr
      $scope.reqDetail($stateParams.gid, dateStr)
    }
  })
}

<input
  ng-model="currDay"
  readonly="readonly"
  id="date-input"
  ng-click="showPicker()"
>
```

I asked in the official issue, the maintainer said it is not the plugin self's problem.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was because of recreateing infinity times, and I solved by this way:

```
$scope.fpCache = []
$scope.showPicker = function() {
if($scope.fpCache.length == 0) {
  const fp = new Flatpickr(document.getElementById('date-input'), {
    locale: zh.zh,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr) {
      $scope.currDay = dateStr
      $scope.searchByDate(dateStr)
    }
  })
  fp.open()
  $scope.fpCache.push(fp)
} else {
  $scope.fpCache[0].open()
}
// $('#date-input').flatpickr({})
// flatpickr(document.getElementById('date-input'), {
//   locale: zh.zh,
//   onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr) {
//     $scope.currDay = dateStr
//     $scope.searchByDate(dateStr)
//   }
// })
}
```

I created a cache array to create the single instance, it works well.